# Input Methods for Anceint Greek (and other diacritic heavy languages)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-method

Let me start by saying that I'm well aware that there's a keyboard layout for Ancient Greek. My issue is that Ancient Greek is a diacritic heavy language, and you can get up to 3 diacritics on a single letter (and not very infrequently, but two is more common). In the current keyboard layouts for Xorg, you have to type all of your diacritics before the letter, and only when you press the letter you can see the result. For example, if I want to write ᾆ, I have to type ][:a. Since Ancient Greek doesn't have keyboards with those diacritics printed, you have to memorize the keys and type them in the correct order.

What I'm looking for is a way to type the accents after the letter, without any particular ordering, and have them appear one by one. What I mean is that typing ᾆ would look something like this:

ἀ -> ἆ -> ᾆ or

ᾶ -> ἆ -> ᾆ

This created the rather strange situation where typing polytonic Greek on Android is easier (but still somewhat slow) than on Linux or on Windows. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, but it's indirect. Install the LibreOffice word processing suite (which is free). In this, install the 'AncientGreek' spelling checker, which includes a keyboard driver that will let you do exactly this. Various layouts are offered. I use the Ibycus layout set to use 'Antioch keys', which on a QWERTY keyboard gives you the nearest possible approach to exact transliteration so you don't need a Greek-marked physical keyboard. Diacritics are retrospectively editable: if you want to change an acute to a grave, position the cursor after the letter and type the grave key. This works even if there are other marks already on the letter.

As far as I know, there is no way of making a simple Linux keyboard driver that gives multiple marks on a letter, as you can in Windows or MacOS. This is a serious gap in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is installing and setting-up an input method framework like `ibus` or `fcitx` (which are generally commonly used for east Asian languages like Mandarin or Japanese, though I use ibus mostly for Ancient Greek and International Phonetic Alphabet…).

Then you can enable the `m17n` input method engine and add the `m17n-mizuochi` for Ancient/classical Greek input method which allows you to input those directly, eg. to write ᾆ you type <kbd>a</kbd> (α), <kbd>J</kbd> (ᾳ), <kbd>^</kbd> [<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>] (ᾷ), <kbd>'</kbd> (ᾆ).

This still requires a specific order of diacritics (eg. <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd> produces nonsense: ἀͺ῀) – but in most graphhical applications you’ll see the result being built up as you type and not appear only at the end.

One limitation which I struggle is that `m17n-mizuochi` doesn’t seem to have any way of inputting the macron, so if you want to mark long vowels, you’ll need to manually input the combining macron character after the vowel yourself somehow (eg. using another keyboard, or direct unicode codepoint inputting method, etc…).

Read more on [Arch Wiki about input methods](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Input_method).